# Is it possible that multiple users perform remote desktop connection to a single session?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, session, multiple-instances

Suppose you have a machine on the cloud running MS Windows Server 2012 R2 as OS on it. You do have a program that can handle multiple sessions running on that machine. But there's a bottleneck that I'm wondering whether it can be handled or not. The machine is allowing only 2 concurrent users get connected via RDP at the same time.
How can I manage and bypass that limitation?
Is there any way to set a remote desktop connection to the very same session? I know that it is possible to have multiple user RDP by tweaking UniversalTermsrvPatch. But what I mean is not that. Any suggestions?

Comment: [More Than 2 Remote Desktop Sessions](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4d9a518-210d-40e9-8638-77e23110cfb3/more-than-2-remote-desktop-sessions?forum=windowshpcitpros) could help you out. From my knowledge it's not possible to have the setup you're describing using RDP.

Comment: You need a Datacenter license that allows up to 10 concurrent sessions. Anything more than that and you need to deploy Remote Desktop Services.

Comment: Yes - 2 is all you get for free. To get more than that costs extra (you'd have o ask MS how much but it's not cheap).